# MySQL Join based on YEAR () indexing - Column add or Generated Column

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, mariadb

Based on the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1601812/4050261

I am using SQL query as below

```
FROM workdone
LEFT JOIN staffcost ON YEAR(workdone.date) = staffcost.costyear
```

The above query does not make use of index which I have on `workdone.date` column and hence very slow. I have 2 options, i presume

### Option 1

Add another column `workdone.year` which is updated through table `oncreate` and `onupdate` event. Use this column in the query.

### Option 2

Add [Generated (Virtual/Persistent)](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/generated-columns/) column `workdone.year` and then use this column in the query.

## My Question:

1. Which option is better? From Performance as well as data duplicity standpoint?
2. Should I use Virtual OR Persistent column type?
3. Is there any better alternative?

---

#### Update 1.1

I implemented the solution suggested by OJones, but explain shows me that index was not used. Am I reading the below screenshot incorrectly?
[image: adminer Explain]

Comment: Does it need to be a LEFT JOIN?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel, Since the 2nd table can have no records, it's essential that the join is LEFT. Does making it INNER Join have performance improvement? If `yes` then can build the application logic to have a mandatory record in the 2nd table and convert the join to INNER join.

Comment: Your approach to solve the problem with a generated column confused me. It's not a solution for this query. You need an index on `staffcost.costyear`.

Comment: With so few rows in the tables, you cannot trust `EXPLAIN` to get the 'right' query plan.  What happens with more rows?  Especially if the data spans more than 10 years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is fine as it is. But a query with a LEFT JOIN can only use an index on the right table (`staffcost`). No index on the left table (`workdone`) can support the join. So all you need is an index on `staffcost(costyear)`.

You can test it with the following script:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `staffcost`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `staffcost` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `costyear` year(4) NOT NULL,
  `data` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `staffcost` (`id`, `costyear`, `data`) VALUES
    (1, '2018', '0.6555866465490187'),
    (2, '2019', '0.12234661925802624'),
    (3, '2020', '0.64497318737672'),
    (4, '2021', '0.8578261098431667'),
    (5, '2022', '0.354211017819318'),
    (6, '2023', '0.19757679030073508'),
    (7, '2024', '0.9252509287793663'),
    (8, '2025', '0.03352430372827156'),
    (9, '2026', '0.3918687630369037'),
    (10, '2027', '0.8587709347333489');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `workdone`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `workdone` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `data` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `date` (`date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `workdone` (`id`, `date`, `data`) VALUES
    (1, '2017-12-31', '0.40540353712197724'),
    (2, '2018-01-01', '0.8716141803857071'),
    (3, '2018-01-02', '0.1418603212962489'),
    (4, '2018-01-03', '0.09445909605776807'),
    (5, '2018-01-04', '0.04671454713373868'),
    (6, '2018-01-05', '0.9501954782290342'),
    (7, '2018-01-06', '0.6108337804776'),
    (8, '2018-01-07', '0.2035824984345422'),
    (9, '2018-01-08', '0.18541118147355615'),
    (10, '2018-01-09', '0.31630844279779907');

EXPLAIN
SELECT * FROM workdone
LEFT JOIN staffcost ON YEAR(workdone.date) = staffcost.costyear;

ALTER TABLE `staffcost` ADD INDEX `costyear` (`costyear`);

EXPLAIN
SELECT * FROM workdone
LEFT JOIN staffcost ON YEAR(workdone.date) = staffcost.costyear;

SELECT VERSION();
```

Results:

```
id|select_type|table    |type|possible_keys|key|key_len|ref|rows|Extra
 1|SIMPLE     |workdone |ALL |             |   |       |   |  10|
 1|SIMPLE     |staffcost|ALL |             |   |       |   |  10|Using where; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join)

id|select_type|table    |type|possible_keys|key     |key_len|ref |rows|Extra
1 |SIMPLE     |workdone |ALL |             |        |       |    |  10|
1 |SIMPLE     |staffcost|ref |costyear     |costyear|1      |func|   1|Using where

VERSION()
10.1.26-MariaDB
```

**Online demo:** http://rextester.com/JIAL51740

Answer (score 3):

You could try this:

```
FROM workdone
LEFT JOIN staffcost ON workdone.date >= MAKEDATE(staffcost.costyear, 1)
                   AND workdone.date <  MAKEDATE(staffcost.costyear+1, 1)
```

This will allow the use of an index on `workdone.date` to search for dates between the first day of the `costyear` up until but not including the first day of `costyear+1`.

In general, this kind of range search can exploit indexes where functions (such as `YEAR(datestamp)`) can't.

Comment: I tried your solution, updated the question with Screenshot. I am using MariaDB 10.1

Comment: For a LEFT JOIN only an index on the right table (`staffcost`) can be used.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel - I agree with you.  However, in some situations, the Optimizer is smart enough to realize that `LEFT` is irrelevant and be willing to do a plain `JOIN`.

Comment: @RickJames - Then it's not a LEFT JOIN - But just a masked INNER JOIN :-)

Comment: I wish people would not hide behind a mask -- Change `LEFT` to `INNER` to clarify the intent.

Answer (score 2):

I think the generated column is much the better option.  It does not make a difference whether or not you persist it.  It does make a difference if you index it.

MySQL (with Innodb) supports indexes on virtual columns.  So, you can do that.  Or persist the column and use that.

That said, I don't think it will make much difference for this query.  A `year` selection is not highly restrictive.  And, you are doing this against another table rather than a constant.  An index on `staffcost(costyear)` seems more important.